# Is there a way to watch all registers for a specific value in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

I'm reverse engineering a c program that has no debugging symbols in GDB.  It asks for a specific 1-15 digit pin number and tells you whether or not it is correct.  My goal is to find out what this pin number is.

I am trouble finding where my pin number guess is compared to the correct pin number.  One method I think would help is to find any place where my guess is loaded into a register.

So on to my question, is it possible to check and see if a specific value is loaded into any register?

For instance I can do this with individual registers by using `watch $rax == 1234`, but I'd like to do this for every register.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to check all general registers at once for a specific value, but you can  combine like $rax == 1234 || $rbx == 1234 || rcx == 1234 || rdx == 1234 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB does not have this functionality.

This sounds like a bad approach, because if the digits are numbers from 0-9 you will get a lot of false positives and you cannot even be sure that is how they are represented.

An easier approach should be to look for changes closely related to the pin entering or failing and tracking the data from there:

- If there is console output when a wrong pin is entered, look for this string in the binary and find where it is referenced.
- Look for references to scanf / printf if this is a console application.
- If it is not using scanf - for example an external keypad, you could find the number of entered digits with a tool like scanmem.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I ended up finding the correct pin number.   I was having trouble finding where my guess was compared to the correct pin.  I turns out checking the registers wouldn't have worked anyways because they were loaded into the register 1 digit at a time (with each digit being represented by a it's ASCII decimal value).

I ended up finding the solution by closing watching compare statements and checking to see what the values in those registers were and how they changed with different guesses.